# R code error "arguments imply differing number of rows" doesn't match the actual dimensions of the data frame after filtering

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to use the package GOchord and I've successfully gotten it to run on a full data frame, but it keeps throwing an error after I try filtering said data frame. Structurally, the filtered dataset appears to match the unfiltered dataset although expectedly smaller. That said, the error message implies the filtered data frame has far more rows than both dim() or str() suggest.

> Error in data.frame(x.end = x.end, y.end = y.end, processID =
> processID) :    arguments imply differing number of rows: 364, 320

The structure of the original dataset that works is the following:

```
> str(chord_input)
'data.frame':   103 obs. of  317 variables:
 $ GO:0000038: int  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0000122: int  0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0000132: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0000187: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0000209: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ GO:0000462: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ GO:0000902: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0001501: int  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0001502: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0001516: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0001525: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0001541: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0001553: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0001558: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
[etc]
```

GOchord runs successfully without error with the following command:

```
GOChord(chord_input)
```

My goal was to filter this data frame to include only columns with a sum of 3 or higher. I attempted many different filtering methods, and all of them appeared to work given the data frame dimensions and structure, yet they all produce the same error that indicates more rows than in either the filtered or unfiltered dataset.

```
> #filt method 1
> chord_input3 = chord_input[,colSums(chord_input) > 2]
> dim(chord_input3)
[1] 103  23
> GOChord(chord_input3)
Error in data.frame(x.end = x.end, y.end = y.end, processID = processID) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 364, 320
> 
> #filt method 2
> chord_input3 <- t(chord_input)
> chord_input3sums <- rowSums(chord_input3)
> chord_input4 <- subset(chord_input3, chord_input3sums > 2)
> chord_input5 <- as.data.frame(t(chord_input4))
> dim(chord_input5)
[1] 103  23
> GOChord(chord_input5)
Error in data.frame(x.end = x.end, y.end = y.end, processID = processID) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 364, 320
> 
> #filt method 3
> chord_input3 <- t(chord_input)
> chord_input4 <- as.data.frame(cbind(sums=rowSums(chord_input3), chord_input3))
> chord_input5 <- chord_input4[chord_input4$sums>=3,]
> chord_input6 <- as.data.frame(t(chord_input5[,-1]))
> dim(chord_input6)
[1] 103  23
> GOChord(chord_input6)
Error in data.frame(x.end = x.end, y.end = y.end, processID = processID) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 364, 320
```

All the data inputs have the same data structure as the original (except in "filt method 3" which contains numeric data instead of integers. For example, after filt method 1 and 2 the structure is as follows:

```
> str(chord_input3)
'data.frame':   103 obs. of  23 variables:
 $ GO:0000122: int  0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0001525: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0002376: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0005975: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0006351: int  0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0006355: int  0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0031175: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0032259: int  0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0032355: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0032611: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0032880: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0043065: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0043066: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GO:0045087: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
[etc]
```

Either way, I've been struggling to figure out where the numbers 364 and 320 are coming from, especially given the fact that both the filtered and unfiltered data frame that runs just fine each have only 103 rows. Any insights are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was finally able to run GOChord on the filtered dataset. Apparently the problem was that I didn't remove rows with all zeroes after filtering the columns. This still doesn't help me interpret the numbers in the error message, but I can at least move on with analysis. Thanks for reading.

```
> #filt method 4
> chord_input3 = chord_input[,colSums(chord_input) > 2]
> chord_input4 = chord_input3[rowSums(chord_input3) > 0,]
> dim(chord_input4)
[1] 59 23
> GOChord(chord_input4)
```